# Add CPT values to Database

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-insert-post

I am not sure if this is something easy. I have a plugin with all the functionality needed for a custom post type: Filters, navegation...

I need to create a lot of posts (with taxonomies) of this CPT (a lot of work is needed to create it properly). So I would like to add this custom posts only once and not each time I want to take advantage of my plugin in other websites...

What is the best way to achieve this? Am I supposed to make some sort of exportation-importation each time? Should I take advantage of wp_insert_post and hardcode the content of the posts?

Apologies for my english, I do not know if I have explained myself...

Thanks¡¡

Comment: Do you want to update all the other websites if you create, update or delete a post on one website?

Comment: Thanks Mike, No. It would be just in the setup step, only at the begining, when installing the plugin. Then the CPT content of each site would be independent...

Comment: What does "to take advantage of my plugin" mean? Are you referring to "installing" the plugin in other sites? Or are you referring to "using the plugin"? Or something else?

Comment: By taking advantage I meant to install the plugin with all the contents so the users of my site could directly browse throuhgt my created CPT's (Without me having to insert all the posts again)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you can get all your CPT data in a `.csv` file, you should be able to write a function that can import it. I have done this for bringing in user tables and/or custom posts when clients migrate from an existing site or software. Here is some example code. You could run this as an include in functions or as part of your plugin, then disable it if you don't need it after the start:

```
// always find line endings
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', true);

// add admin menu
add_action('admin_menu', 'csvimporter_menu');

function csvimporter_menu() {   
    add_submenu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=physician', 'CSV Importer', 'Import', 'manage_options', 'csv-importer', 'csvimporter');   
}

// show importer form
function csvimporter() {
    global $wpdb;
    if (!current_user_can('manage_options')) {
        wp_die( __('You do not have rights to access this page.') );
    }

    // when form is submitted
    if ($_POST['mode'] == "submit") {

        $arr_rows = file($_FILES['csv_file']['tmp_name']);

        // process the rows
        if (is_array($arr_rows)) {
            foreach ($arr_rows as $row) {

                // split into values -- note I prefer to separate by semicolon, you must setup your CSV to match this delimiter
                $arr_values = split(";", $row);

                // these will need rekeyed!! this is just an example!! In this example I build a long title from the physician's name
                $name    = $arr_values[0]; //fname
                $name   .= (empty($arr_values[1]) ? '' : ' '  .$arr_values[1]); //mname
                $name   .= (empty($arr_values[2]) ? '' : ' '  .$arr_values[2]); //lname
                $name   .= (empty($arr_values[3]) ? '' : ' '  .$arr_values[3]); //suffix
                $name   .= (empty($arr_values[4]) ? '' : ', ' .$arr_values[4]); //first degree
                $name   .= (empty($arr_values[5]) ? '' : ', ' .$arr_values[5]); //second degree

                // add the new post
                $arr_post = array(  'comment_status' => 'closed',
                                    'ping_status' => 'closed',
                                    'post_author' => 1,
                                    'post_title' => $name,
                                    'post_status' => 'publish', 
                                    'post_type' => 'physician',                                 
                                    );
                $post_id = wp_insert_post( $arr_post );

                // add all the meta values
                $arr_meta_values = array(
                    '_cmb_last_name'    => $arr_values[2],
                    '_cmb_board_1'      => $arr_values[6],
                    '_cmb_board_2'      => $arr_values[7],
                    '_cmb_group_name'   => $arr_values[11],
                    '_cmb_address_1'    => $arr_values[12],
                    '_cmb_address_2'    => $arr_values[13].(!empty($arr_values[14]) ? ', '.$arr_values[14] : ''),
                    '_cmb_city'         => $arr_values[15],
                    '_cmb_state'        => $arr_values[16],
                    '_cmb_zip'          => $arr_values[17],
                    '_cmb_phone'        => $arr_values[18],
                    '_cmb_status'       => $arr_values[19]
                );

                // fill up terms if you wish
                $taxonomy = 'physician-specialty';
                $terms = array();
                if(!empty($arr_values[8])){
                    // get ID if is term
                    $term_id = is_term($arr_values[8]);
                    if($term_id != 0){
                        // is term, add to list
                        $terms[] = $term_id;
                    } else {
                        // is not term, create, then add to list
                        wp_insert_term($arr_values[8], $taxonomy);
                        $term_id = is_term($arr_values[8]);
                        $terms[] = $term_id;
                    }
                }
                // assuming more term columns are there...
                if(!empty($arr_values[9])){
                    $term_id = is_term($arr_values[9]);
                    if($term_id != 0){
                        $terms[] = $term_id;
                    } else {
                        wp_insert_term($arr_values[9], $taxonomy);
                        $term_id = is_term($arr_values[9]);
                        $terms[] = $term_id;
                    }
                }
                // add all terms at once
                wp_set_post_terms($post_id, $terms, $taxonomy);

                foreach($arr_meta_values as $key => $value) {
                    update_post_meta($post_id, $key, $value);
                }
            }

            $html_update = "<div class='updated'>It worked! I think.</div>";
        } else {
            $html_update = "<div class='updated' style='color: red'>Something went terribly wrong!</div>";          
        }
    }
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">  
        <?php echo $html_update; ?> 
        <div id="icon-plugins" class="icon32"><br /></div>
        <h2>CSV Importer</h2>
        <p>Select the CSV file you want to import</p>

        <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="hidden" name="mode" value="submit">
            <input type="file" name="csv_file" />       
            <input type="submit" value="Import" />
        </form>

        <p>The CSV file should be in this sweet, sweet format. Oh yea!</p>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>firstname;</td>
                <td>middlename;</td>            
                <td>lastname;</td>
                <td>blah;</td>
                <td>etc;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <p style="color: red">Please make sure you back up your database before proceeding!</p> 
    </div>
    <?php
}
?>
```

You'll need to make sure your `CSV` is setup properly. I strongly suggest backing up database and running only a **sample** dataset (20 rows) to ensure this is working properly. Note my example has only a sampling of my own data needs. The end result can include many more `meta_keys`, taxonomy stuff, actual content, etc. Just be sure you choose a good delimiter for your `CSV`. Excel might not let you setup the `CSV` just how you want, I recommend OpenOffice.

Comment: Thanks GhostToast, I am going to adapt it to my needs and have it tested. Any other solution is more than welcome but yours matches what i was looking for.